# Laravel installs with no vendor folder

Tags: laravel-5

I am installing Laravel with Composer and don't remember having this issue in the past, but now it is installing without the vendor folder. Is this an error within the installer or new expected behavior?

thanks

Comment: You need to check if in your `composer.json` file exists a key called `config` with a different `vendor-dir`.

Comment: I am using `composer create-project` and of course, that `.json` file doesn't exist until after the project is created. Just not getting the vendor dir for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a `composer.json` in the root directory?

if so, run `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling seemed to work. Never got an answer regarding why this happened.